# Please kindly help me to understand this sentence

Tags: word-usage

I'm watching Schitt's Creek Season 1- Ep 1, there is this sentence I'm not sure I understand correctly. Please advise.

> There's a pharmacy worth of drugs wearing off on most of us right now, and I just think as a family, we need a little time to chill.

--> Did he mean that the drugs they're using are wearing off and they need time to chill?

The whole conversation:

> That was an overreaction. That was uncalled for. It's just, you know, we're a little tired. It's been a long day. There's a pharmacy worth of drugs wearing off on most of us right now, and I just think as a family, we need a little time to chill.

Thank you!

Comment: Yes, it means the whole family use lots of prescription drugs, and their effects are wearing off, which can cause people to react badly to things. I believe in this scene they're stranded somewhere or have lost their luggage, so they don't have access to their pills to take more and keep themselves level-headed

Answer (score 2):

What it means is that the speaker is asserting that most of the family members have been taking a lot of drugs (as many drugs as are in a pharmacy is hyperbole) and so are emotionally volatile.